# for loop to dynamically output a result

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how to dynamically output a result using a for loop i have tried this but it hasnt worked, any ideas?

```
              <select class="form-control">
                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                <option> ACS40 + i +  </option>;

                <option>ACS401</option>
                <option>ACS402</option>
                <option>ACS403</option>
                <option>ACS404</option>
                <option>ACS405</option>
                <option>ACS406</option>
                }
              </select>
```

Comment: Your question is not really conceise. You try to use Javascript as part of HTML? Sounds great, doesn't work.

Comment: This looks like an HTML/JS mashup.

Comment: Why there is `for` loop inside html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using JavaScript way to create the `select` and corresponding `option` element,

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('form');

//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.class = "form-control";
myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var content = "ACS40" + i;
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.setAttribute("value", content);
  option.text = content;
  selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<div id='form'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop and [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). And during each loop add `string` to `innerHTML` of the `<select>` using `+=`

```js
let sel = document.querySelector('.form-control');
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  sel.innerHTML += `<option>ACS40${i} </option>`
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Vanilla Javascript

Use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the element, and [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to modify the html through javascript.

```js
var select = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control')[0];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
  select.innerHTML += `<option> ACS40${i}</option>`;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control">

</select>
```

## jQuery

Or you can use jQuery like below. This code uses [jQuery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) to select the element, and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to modify the html

```js
var select = $(".form-control");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
  select.append(`<option> ACS40${i}</option>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">

</select>
```

Comment: I have already answered the question.There is no new thing in your answer. Please try not to spam the same answers

Comment: @MaheerAli read the answer again. And I didn't see your answer earlier

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it.

```js
let sel = document.getElementById('test');

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  sel.appendChild(createOpt("ASBLA 40"+ i));
}

function createOpt(content){
  let el = document.createElement("option");
  el.innerHTML = content;
  return el;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <select id="test">
 </select>
</div>
```